# Can't tell if Stash cache is working

Tags: stash, cache, caching

I have two chunks of data in the same 'viewModel' template:

```
{!-- Getting data for kitchen list --}
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="kitchen_list"
    parse_tags="yes"
    save="yes"
    scope="site"
    refresh="1440"
    replace="no"
}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="kitchen_list"
    disable="member_data|pagination|categories"
  }
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
    {stash:url_title_path}{url_title_path='sky-island-natural-foods/whats-cooking'}{/stash:url_title_path}
    {stash:description_brief}{kitchen_description_brief}{/stash:description_brief}
    {stash:description_full}{kitchen_description_full}{/stash:description_full}
    {stash:photo_product}{kitchen_photo_product}{/stash:photo_product}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- Getting data for kitchen list page --}
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="kitchen_page"
    parse_tags="yes"
    save="yes"
    scope="site"
    refresh="1440"
    replace="no"
}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="kitchen_page"
    disable="member_data|pagination|categories"
    limit="1"
  }
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:sidebar_heading}{kitchen_page_sidebar_heading}{/stash:sidebar_heading}
    {stash:sidebar}{kitchen_page_sidebar}{/stash:sidebar}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

It all works fine, but when I look at the stash table with Sequel Pro as I navigate the pages, it seems that the kitchen_list does not get rewritten to the database (I thought replace="no" took care of this) on each subsequent page visit, but kitchen_page does get rewritten every time I revisit a page which uses that data. So there are multiple row in the table for kitchen_page with identical data, just different IDs, but there is only one row for kitchen_list.

I expected that by caching the fragments of data and using replace="no", I would only see a single row in the stash table for that fragment, no matter how many times the stash list was called.

I can't tell if there is something off with my code, or just my assumptions/understanding of the caching. Thank you.

Comment: Using the template debugger, it seems every time the page loads, kitchen_page is SET and later RETRIEVED, whereas kitchen_list is simply RETRIEVED as it is already cached. I'm seeing this in a lot of my templates—stash lists that are set with caching are being SET on each page load rather than just retrieved once the cache has been written.

Comment: What version of stash are you using? i just now tested with 2.4.6 and can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in your browser? Are you using a subdomain with an underscore _ in the name? What timezone is your EE site set to and your server?

Comment: I'm using v2.4.6

Comment: Cookies are enabled, I see the exp_stashid cookie. I'm not using a subdomain locally. The timezone is America/Los_Angeles in ExpressionEngine and in my php.ini file. I have auto detect in the config for DST.

Comment: I pushed the site up to a staging server to see if it was an environmental issue, but again, rows are added every time on page refresh.

Comment: I just realized that it only occurs when I'm logged in to EE. When I'm logged out, the cache stays put and doesn't get rewritten. I wondered it it was connected with the Stash Breaker extension, but even with this disabled, the same occurs. Is this by design?

Comment: The {exp:stash:flush_cache} tag only runs for a logged in super admin. Check your templates to see if you have used it somewhere.

Comment: I haven't used that tag anywhere. The previous cached fragments remain in the db, they are not flushed, as they are when I use the stash breaker extension and update and entry or Low Variable. There just end up being a bunch of duplicate entries in the stash table with the Id being the only differentiating factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. I am using a config bootstrap which I set up when I was first learning ExpressionEngine and haven't looked at it much since, apart from updating db settings etc.

I had:
`$config['enable_db_caching'] = "y";`

and EE was caching the stash chunks before stash could which was causing all the trouble when I was logged in. I've turned this setting off in the config now and it is behaving as expected.

I now realize this setting was causing problems with some of the other modules I'm using. A few issues I've had now make sense!

Answer (score 2):

If your code above is in a Stash file (i.e., not a regular EE template), double-check to make sure that you have this Stash config set:

`$config['stash_file_sync'] = TRUE;`

I've had this happen to me a few times: I make a change in a Stash file, forget that I have that setting set to `FALSE`, and wonder why my code isn't working as expected.

Comment: The above code is in an EE template. The layout and partials are stash files, but the data templates are EE. My config is set to `$config['stash_file_sync'] = TRUE;` already. Thanks for response, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I cannot reproduce this problem. Logged in/out, cookies enabled or disabled, I find that the cached items are generated only once until they expire. Tested with both EE 2.6.1 and EE 2.7.2 and Stash 2.4.6.

To rule out a server vs php timezone configuration issue (where the expiry date may fall in the the past of the server) please try with `refresh="0"` (never expires).

You mentioned you are using a third party cache-breaking extension. Please remove this extension entirely from your system folder and make sure it is not listed in the `exp_extensions` table (if it is, delete the record). Make sure that the Stash extension IS installed.

Please truncate your `exp_stash` table, and delete your cookies for the testing domain.

Create a new template with only your code above in it, and view it.

Do you still have the problem? If so, as you are using `scope="site"` the session_id in the stash table for each variable should be `_global`. Is that the case or do you see a long string of characters?